# Trigger Lambda function when object is deleted from S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pysftp

I have an SFTP server and Lambda function. Lambda function is  triggered when an object is uploaded to S3 and the object is automatically uploaded to SFTP server via SFTP. (I'm using pysftp)

Is it possible to create a Lambda function that will trigger once the object gets deleted from S3 and to delete it automatically from the server?

```
import pysftp,os,boto3

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

myHostname = os.environ.get('SFTP_HOST')
myUsername = os.environ.get('SFTP_USER')
myPassword = os.environ.get('SFTP_PASS')

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get the records for the triggered event
    FILEOBJ = event["Records"][0]
    BUCKET_NAME = str(FILEOBJ['s3']['bucket']['name'])
    KEY = str(FILEOBJ['s3']['object']['key'])
    FILE_NAME = os.path.basename(KEY)

    with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
      with sftp.cd('data/uploads'):
        remote_file = FILE_NAME
        sftp.remove(remote_file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use S3 event with Event type `s3:ObjectRemoved:*` and trigger Lambda functions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations.html

If you want to use the same function with S3 upload, you can find and use the info in `event` that Lambda function get like `eventName': 'ObjectCreated:Put` or `eventName': 'ObjectRemoved:Delete`.

Comment: I have used that type of Event and I have created a similar function to the one I posted above.

Comment: Is that working? If not, can you share the function to delete?

Comment: yes, it's working, I've edited the code above to match

Comment: Good to hear that. If the answer was helpful, its acceptance would be appreciated.